# how to use reporting verbs with 'that' clauses

Tags: verbs

```
_____describe       _____discuss        _____assert _____contend
_____state          _____present        _____note   _____allege
_____explain        _____maintain       _____claim  _____imply
_____examine        _____affirm         _____argue  _____reveal
_____presume        _____assume
```

I am teaching students how to write a summary using reporting verbs.Here are a few reporting verbs I am trying to teach. Yesterday I was reviewing various functions of 'that' clauses. A student asked me
Q:Which of the verbs above take a *that* clause? Which never take a *that* clause?

I don't want to give the student the wrong answer, so any input from the experts?

Comment: Almost all of them can easily take a *that*-clause, as can be found with a sentence like "We can state that it happens". *Describe* is slightly awkward, and *examine* probably doesn't work. Why does that methodology not work for you?

Comment: @AndrewLeach *Describe, examine* and *discuss* normally take interrogative clauses which is why they don't work well with declarative *that* ones.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of tensed clauses, content clauses beginning with the subordinator *that* are always declarative. Most of the verbs in that list that don't freely take content clause with *that* most commonly take interrogative clauses as complements instead of declarative ones.

The verbs *describe, examine* and *discuss* don't readily take content clauses using the subordinator *that*. All three can take freely interrogative clauses starting with a *wh-* word.

**Interrogative content clauses**

- I shall describe what happened.
- Let's examine who the culprit might be.
- Let's discuss what we're going to do.

However, the verbs *describe* and *discuss* can take declarative content clauses using the specialised subordinator *how*. This subordinator is often used with verbs that take interrogative content clauses to enable them to take declarative ones:

**Declarative content clauses with *how***

- So I described to the Police how Bertha had come in and beaten everyone up.
- So then we discussed how London was such a rubbish place to live and how Berlin was even worse but Barcelona was fantastic.

Notice that in these two sentences the speaker doesn't mean the method that Bertha had used or that we discussed the question *In which ways is London a rubbish place to live*. The speaker probably really just wants to say that they talked about the fact *that London was a rubbish place to live*.

There are times when it can be ambiguous as whether a speaker is using an interrogative content clause or a declarative one:

- Describe how you escaped from Colditz.

**Note**

The Original Poster - and anyone else who's interested - might find [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49448/using-that-or-how-after-describe/49477#49477) about the verb *describe* worth a look.

Comment: "Content clauses beginning with the subordinator _that_ are always declarative" -- only the tensed ones. The untensed ones are often called "subjunctive".

Comment: @JohnLawler Quite right. Had forgotten about "mandative" and all of that stuff. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't call them "subjunctive", then you have nothing to contrast "declarative" with, and it becomes vacuous. On the other hand,  if you don't need subjunctive, you don't need declarative either. English just doesn't have moods, is all. Constructions, yes; the "interrogative content clauses" (not a great term, that -- they aren't interrogative in function and all clauses have content) are also called Embedded Question Complement clauses, as well as Headless Relative clauses. They're complex structures.

Comment: @JohnLawler Interrogative content clauses is straight out of CaGEL, Huddleston & Pullum. They wouldn't contrast declarative with subjunctive. They'd contrast declarative with interrogative & exclamative.  They (nor I) regard declarative as a mood but a clause type.  A content clause for them is just the default subordinate clause type contrasting with comparative or relative constructions. Called "content" because selected for it's semantic  content. They reserve the term "embedded question"  to refer to the questions represented by subordinate interrogative clauses ...

Comment: @JohnLawler So the embedded question in relation to the interrogative content clause *why they asked him* would be "why did they ask him". I'm not aware of people using the term *declarative* in the way that people use(d) the term "indicative" - although they might well do so.

Comment: No, embedded questions have question form (they start with a _Wh_-word moved from the clause) but they don't undergo Subject-Auxiliary Inversion. So a real question would be _Why did they ask him?_, a complete interrogative sentence, with a _Wh_-word and Inversion; but an embedded question would be _why they asked him_, a subordinate noun clause with a _Wh_-word but no Inversion, and no intrinsic interrogative function. it can be part of _I told him why ..._ or of _I wonder why .._; the latter can have interrogative function, and Inversion is optional: _I wonder why did they ask him?_

Comment: @JohnLawler Well that's just a difference in terminology between you and them, isn't it? Substitute your embedded question with their interrogative content clause and the description's the same. They don't call interrogative content clauses questions!

Comment: The question is whether it's a name or a description. If it actually describes, then its parts should be precisely defined, and they aren't. If it's just a name and not a description, then **it** needs to be precisely defined. That can be done with the terms I  used. That's what accuracy means.

Comment: @JohnLawler Hmm, I'm just a beginner, but are you saying that CaGEL isn't precise with its terminology? It seems to me that they go out of their way to be precise and to define their terms clearly.  It seems to me to have some principled distinctions. So for example they use the term "interrogative" to refer to syntactic types of clause and "questions" to refer to a semantic/pragmatic type of utterance. So they would never say something like "question form" to refer to an interrogative form, because of course questions can have a "declarative form". A useful distinction, it seems.

Comment: I understand H&P's impulse to rationalize nomenclature; and I like some of their innovations -- intransitive prepositions, for instance, make a lot of sense. But they often used words with specific senses in other theories, so that, despite their desire to be atheoretic, you often need to look up a whole lot of other terms, and their special senses in H&P to see what the hell theyre talking about. I see what youre saying; but it's hard promulgating a new and improved terminology.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, couldn't agree more. It also makes it difficult for people who start out with H&P when they they then branch out and start  talking to linguists from other backgrounds too, as I'm finding out ... –

Comment: @Rathony Yes, indeed. Don't know how come I missed those!!! Thanks. Much better :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a worthwhile project.  An interesting reporting verb that is used for utterances that are not sentences is "go": "He went [makes rude noise]." Of course, there is no "that", which only goes with sentences in indirect discourse. A friend, Paul Kay, noticed that his children had started using "go" where "say" is used in standard English.

Comment: At least the children haven't picked up "I'm, like, 'yeah?'...".

Comment: I use *go* as a reporting verb all the time too. It can only be used with citations as you point out: "And then he went *what you gonna do about it then* and then *she* went *why don't you come over here and find out, son* and then he was giving it all of *I'm not taking any of that from you, you jumped up librarian* and then she went and smacked him over the head with a snooker cue". I wonder if *to give it all of* should be considered a reporting idiom too?