# Is "I like how when + phrase" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> I like how when Katy asked "Is everything okay?", Lilly asked "Is it not?".

Comment: I like the way Katy asked.....

Comment: It's comprehensible, at least. I'd consider it colloquial but grammatically valid.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In this case *how* is roughly interchangeable with *that*, and while maybe a little clunky, the phrase is grammatically correct. In this example there's no clearly superior way to phrase it (that I can think of) other than "I like how..."

**EDIT**: Here is why I consider *how* and *that* roughly interchangeable **in the OP's sentence:** Simply put, swapping one for the other has no impact on the sentence's logical flow or meaning. Either way, the causal relationship between Katy's question and Lily's reply is clearly established, and that's the role "I like how/that when" is intended to fulfill.

Comment: I don't think how is interchangeable with *that* in the Original Poster's sentence. Can you elaborate on the reason why you think *how* is roughly interchangeable with *that*?

Comment: @Rathony See [this post here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278105/how-to-use-reporting-verbs-with-that-clauses/278143#278143) or [this one here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49448/using-that-or-how-after-describe/49477#49477). H&P class  *how* as a subordinator (like *that*) when used this way.

Comment: +1 from me. There's a lot of evidence that *how* like the word *that* is a subordinator here.

Comment: @Araucaria If you contrast "we discussed how London was such a rubbish place to live" with **we discussed how rubbish a place London was to live**, I am not sure if you see any difference? If you contrast both of them with "we talked about the fact that London was a rubbish place to live", what is your thought?

Comment: @Rathony Your first sentence is ambiguous between *how* being an interrogative word and a subordinator - but your second is an subordinate exclamative clause :-) The embedded clauses in the first one could be *London is a rubbish place to live* or *London  is a rubbish place to live in these ways*. The third is *How rubbish a place London is to live* or *How rubbish London is to live in*.

Comment: @Araucaria One of the major properties of the three words that you listed in your linked post is that they are used to emphasize the process of actions, e.g., the sentence *I described to the Police how he had come in and beaten everyone up* could result in various questions. "you said he had come in running, how fast was he? Fast enough that no guard could see him? You said he had beaten them up with a baseball bat. Was it an aluminum bat or wooden bat? What size? For kids or Major League? Was it broken during the beating? etc. I don't agree that the speaker doesn't mean the method.

Comment: @Rathony If that's the way the conversation was going then that would seem to  be an interrogative. But very often that isn't the way it goes. For example in a sentence such as *She described how she wasn't going to be there on Thursday* it would seem to be entirely non-interrogative. You can read about *how* as a subordinator [here](https://ia800504.us.archive.org/16/items/TheCambridgeGrammarOfTheEnglishLanguage/The%20Cambridge%20grammar%20of%20the%20English%20language.pdf#page=968&zoom=auto,-242,851)

Comment: @Araucaria I am not denying the fact that *how* could be used as a *subordinator*. It could *in a limited number of cases*, I guess. But people choose to use *how* because it has a different function than *that*, e.g., "She described how she managed to get there under such heavy traffic." could mean a completely different thing. It could be followed by "She turned out to be a marathoner. She ditched her car and ran 15 miles to make it.".

Comment: @Rathony Yes,  agree :)

Comment: @Rathony I like the fact how *how* can be used as a subordinator!

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, indeed. Because English... :-)

Answer (score 2):

On the surface the phrasing feels redundant. However it falls in line with similar colloquial gems such as "also too" and "I know, right?" (The latter being a debatable case of reverse redundancy). As cumbersome as it is on the ear of a lingual enthusiast, it is a difficult one to argue based solely on grammar. Its widespread use is the single factor that makes it a battle best left unfought.

Comment: It does't seem redundant to me. "I like how Katie asked..." would mean something entirely different, and "I like when Katie asked..." is maybe grammatical, but feels too abrupt to me.